# Extension of function space to vector-valued function space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

The usual definition of function space, say $L^2(X)$, is defined as the set of square integrable functions $f: X \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, which says
$$
\int_X f(x)^2 dx < +\infty.
$$

However, I am interested in a vector-valued function $f: X \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$.

**Question**: what is the proper mathematical way to define a vector-valued function space? Is that a direct sum $L^2(X) \bigoplus L^2(X) $ or it should be tensor product $L^2(X) \bigotimes L^2(X)$? Or something else?

Comment: For vector valued functions we need the tensor product $L^2(X) \otimes \mathbb{R}^2$ with induced scalar product. The tensor product $L^2(X) \otimes L^2(X)$ is instead a subspace of $L^2(X \times X)$. Elements of $L^2(X) \oplus L^2(X)$ are pairs of functions $(f,g)$ so that is something different as well.

Comment: @jd27 thank you. so I guess pairs of function $(f,g)$ isn't directly connected to any function space?

Comment: You can simply define the $L^2$ norm of a function $f \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ in the obvious way and verify that it satisfies all of the same properties as $L^ 2(X)$. There’s no need to use the terms tensor product or direct sum unless you are trying to do some abstract functional analysis.